# Need Chrome in Jenkins to run Karma tests

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I need Chrome in Jenkins to run Karma tests. I get the following error:

```
ERROR [launcher]: No binary for ChromeHeadless browser on your platform. Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
```

I have tried installing chromium and puppeteer with NodeJS from "Global Tool Configuration" but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: How do I install it in Jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins runs from a Red Hat image in OpenShift.

Comment: Given this [Jenkins chromedriver plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/chromedriver/) is 6+years old, I can't imagine it still works. You'd have to [pre-install it](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) by whatever means works for you. wget, unzip, add to PATH?

Comment: Before to run the tests with jenkins, try to running directly. Share us the result.